# Install XAMPP as non-admin

Tags: php, linux, xampp

I need to install xampp as a normal user and run PHP server with a non-default port.

I have changed the 'Listen 80' in ~/lampp/etc/httpd.conf to another port.

But when i start it using ~/lampp/lampp start, it complains

> You need to start XAMPP as root!

Is there any way to run this without root login ?

Comment: I sure hope that's not possible...

Comment: ports under 1024 can only be bound to by the root user

Comment: but, I'm using port 5555 in httpd.conf

Answer (score 0):

You need to install xampp as root, but you can run as normal user.

Here is the step by step guides for the same.

http://forums.bizhat.com/linux-freebsd-opensource/41058-how-install-xampp-ubuntu-linux-running-normal-user.html